# PHP Convert byte array as string into pdf

Tags: php, arrays, string, pdf

I have a byte array in string format in php from SOAP Webservice , want to convert to pdf .

Web service Response Data

```
<RunProcessResponse IsReport="true" ReportFormat="pdf" xmlns="http://ie.org/ADInterface/1_0">
            <Data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ata>
</RunProcessResponse>
```

PHP Code:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="service.pdf"');
echo base64_decode($byte_string);
```

Webservice return pdf response in JAVA

Java Code :

```
file_type ="pdf";               
RunProcessResponse r= res.addNewRunProcessResponse();                        
r.setData(java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(pi.getPDFReport().toPath()));
r.setReportFormat(file_type);
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Do you have a byte array as string or a base64 encoded string? The example in your question looks like neither

Comment: byte array as string

Comment: It looks like it's been converted to hex, not base64.

Comment: Does this webservice offer any documentation? If so, what encoding does it suggest?

Comment: http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Web_services

Comment: @MagnusEriksson looks like you're correct. Decoding from hex produces some legible binary. For example, the header is `%PDF-1.5` but the entire file is not a valid PDF

Comment: I would contact the service owners and ask them about it. That documentation was pretty poor. It only tells what params it returns, not in what format or how you should use the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick test suggests the string is encoded as [Base16 (hexadecimal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Base16_(Transfer_encoding)) (an odd choice).

PHP has a handy function available in [`hex2bin()`](http://php.net/manual/function.hex2bin.php)

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="service.pdf"');
echo hex2bin($byte_string);
exit;
```